OPC UA .NET SDK How to write to predefined nodes
I am trying to write to predefined nodes that I import from a nodeset2 xml file and cannot find out how to update the value from a connected machine.
I want to write to the "Value" attribute of the node but I cannot find out how.
I know that one can declare an object and then just set the attribute by setting: object.Value = 123, but as I want this to work irrespective of what nodeset is imported , this is not an option.
I have tried the handle.Node.WriteAttribute(SystemContext, nodeToRead.AttributeId, nodeToRead.ParsedIndexRange, value); and call this within the "Read" callback method within the NodeManager to achieve amn "on read updating" but this just returns a "BadNotWriteable". I have tried chaning the permissions, but surely the server itself should have the permissions to access its own data...
I have also tried handle.Node.SetChildValue(SystemContext, handle.Node.BrowseName, val, true); but this just returns "false".
Would be very grateful for any help here!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
